# Swift: assign to variable in switch case-let-where

Tags: swift

Is it possible to make an assignment to the artist variable **before** it is used in the where subclause?

```
var artist
switch fullline {
case let path where path.hasPrefix("Monet"):
    artist = "Monet"
case let path where path.hasPrefix("Cezanne"):
    artist = "Cezanne"
default: ()
}
```

**Closure:**

```
case let path where { () -> Bool in let artist = "Monet"; return path.hasPrefix(artist) }:
```

**Error:**

> () -> Bool' is not convertible to 'Bool'

**Context:**

I have lines of freeform text with artist name as the prefix that requires
massaging to output consistent humanly readable text. e.g.

> ```
> Monet : Snow at Argenteuil 02, 1874
> Monet - Snow at Argenteuil, 1874, 3rd Floor Collections
> Monet, Claude - 1875, Snow in Argenteuil
> Cezzane - Vase of Flowers, 1880-81, print
> Cezzane, Paul 1900-1903 Vase of Flowers
> Cezzane - Vase with Flowers, 1895-1896
> ```

There will be a code fragments that performs detailed processing/categorizing
for each artist. Hence the processing logic is artist dependent.

I would like to define similar to the following construct

```
switch fullline
hasPrefix(artist = "Monet")  
    -> code logic 1
       get_birthday(artist)

hasPrefix(artist = "Cezzane")
    -> code logic 2
       get_birthday(artist)
```

Comment: example for `fullline`?

Comment: can't you just write: case let path.hasPrefix("Monet") and omit there where clause

Comment: how is it different from your first case?

Comment: @ato3787045 You're giving that closure where a boolean is expected. Perhaps you meant to call the closure by using `()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little modification to the Alexander's struct, you can write something like this:

```
struct PrefixMatcherWithHandler {
    var handler: (String)->Void
    var string: String
    init(_ string: String, handler: @escaping (String)->Void) {
        self.string = string
        self.handler = handler
    }

    static func ~= (prefix: String, matcher: PrefixMatcherWithHandler) -> Bool {
        if matcher.string.hasPrefix(prefix) {
            matcher.handler(prefix)
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

var fullline: String = "Monet, Claude"

var artist: String? = nil

let matcher = PrefixMatcherWithHandler(fullline) {str in
    artist = str
}

switch matcher {
case "Monet":
    break
case "Cezanne":
    break
default: break
}
print(artist ?? "") //->Monet
```

But having some side-effect in boolean operators like `~=` makes your code less readable and can easily make unexpected result.

If you just want to reduce some redundant reference to a same thing, `switch`-statement may not be a good tool for it.

For example, you can get the same result without defining specific matcher types:

```
var fullline: String = "Monet, Claude"

var artist: String? = nil

if let match = ["Monet", "Cezanne"].first(where: {fullline.hasPrefix($0)}) {
    artist = match
}
print(artist ?? "") //->Monet
```

---

**ADDED** for updated parts of the question

The following code behaves slightly different than prefix-matching, but I believe you do not want to match `"Mon"` to the line `Monet, Claude - 1875, Snow in Argenteuil`.

```
extension String {
    var firstWord: String? {
        var result: String? = nil
        enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..<endIndex, options: .byWords) {str, _, _, stop in
            result = str
            stop = true
        }
        return result
    }
}

func get_birthday(_ artist: String) {
    //What do you want to do?
    print(artist)
}

var fullline: String = "Monet, Claude - 1875, Snow in Argenteuil"

switch fullline.firstWord {
case let artist? where artist == "Monet":
    //code dedicated for "Monet"
    get_birthday(artist)
case let artist? where artist == "Cezanne":
    //code dedicated for "Cezanne"
    get_birthday(artist)
default:
    break
}
```

When you can retrieve data suitable for `switch`-statement, the code would be far more intuitive and readable.

Comment: Ahhh, i'm not a fan of that. That's a pretty unintuitive side effect. The last code snippet is what I would prefer, though

Comment: @Alexander, indeed. I never use it in my apps, just a code play.

Comment: Thank you, OOPer! Swift and Foundation are indeed expressive.

Answer (score 2):

You're giving that closure where a boolean is expected. Not sure why you would want to do this, but you could make it work by using `()` to invoke the closure.

```
var artist
switch fullline {
case let path where { () -> Bool in let artist = "Monet"; return path.hasPrefix(artist) }():
    artist = "Monet"
case let path where path.hasPrefix("Cezanne"):
    artist = "Cezanne"
default: ()
}
```

Here is how I would do this:

```
import Foundation

struct PrefixMatcher {
    let string: String
    init(_ string: String) { self.string = string }

    static func ~= (prefix: String, matcher: PrefixMatcher) -> Bool {
        return matcher.string.hasPrefix(prefix)
    }
}

extension String {
    var prefix: PrefixMatcher { return PrefixMatcher(self) }
}


let fullline = "Monet 123456789"

let artist: String?

switch fullline.prefix {
    case "Monet": artist = "Monet"
    case "Cezanne": artist = "Cezanne"
    default: artist = nil
}

print(artist as Any)
```

More general solution:

```
import Foundation

struct PredicateMatcher<Pattern> {
    typealias Predicate = (Pattern) -> Bool

    let predicate: Predicate

    static func ~=(pattern: Pattern,
                   matcher: PredicateMatcher<Pattern>) -> Bool {
        return matcher.predicate(pattern)
    }
}

extension String {
    var prefix: PredicateMatcher<String> {
        return PredicateMatcher(predicate: self.hasPrefix)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight, Alexander! The Prefix/PredicateMatcher example you gave is a better solution.

Looking at it again closely reveals the following subtlety when using () to invoke the closure at each case-let-where: as the switch statement sequentially executes each closure, the variable artist will ***always*** be
assigned to the value of the last case!

I am trying find a succinct syntax without using string literal twice. Is it possible to get at the **case** string(e.g. "Monet") within the case body?

Comment: `let` declarations within closures are local to the scope they're defined in, so that won't help you with creating an `artist` variable to use within the case body. Could you give me more of an explanation of *what* exactly you're trying to achieve (rather than *how* you're trying to achieve it?)

Comment: Alexander, I am trying to keep the string literal("Monet") close to the code fragment(case body) that uses it without duplicating the literal. So future developers can modify the literal at exactly one place. The case body code fragment will be different for different artists depending on the context provided by the rest of the fullline. Sometimes it will append additional string to the case value(e.g "Monet from 3rd Floor Collections", "Cezzane Tulips in a Vase 1890").

Comment: @ato3787045 " The case body code fragment will be different for different artists depending on the context provided by the rest of the fullline. " Can you elaborate on this? You're explaining what you're goals are with respect how you want to improve this existing code snippet, but you haven't explained to me what the problem is you're trying to solve. What is this code *meant* to do (without any regard for HOW it does it, I don't care about that)

Comment: Alexander, I added the context to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by switching over a tuple of your enum and your optional.
Optional is an enum too, so you can switch both of them

```swift
enum SomeSnum {
   case a, b, c
}

let someString: String? = "something"
let esomeEnum = SomeSnum.b

switch(esomeEnum, someString) {
case (.b, .some(let unwrappedSomething)) where unwrappedSomething.hasPrefix("so"):
    print("case .b, \(unwrappedSomething) is unwrapped, and it has `so` prefix")

case (.a, .none):
    print("case .a, and optional is nil")

default:
    print("Something else")
}
```

You can also do an if statement

```swift
if case let (.b, .some(unwrappedSomething)) = (esomeEnum, someString), unwrappedSomething.hasPrefix("so") {

} else if case (.a, .none) = (esomeEnum, someString) {

} else {

}
```